# How to use CASE in SQL , Syntax Error being shown

Tags: sql-server-2005, database, sql

I am trying to retrieve some records from table based on my query but it shows me an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>       Incorrect syntax near '>

```
select vd.LedgerId,(CreditAmt-DebitAmt) AS NET, CASE NET
WHEN NET > 0 THEN 'Debit' WHEN NET < 0 THEN 'Credit' ELSE 'Nil'End
from dbo.vdebit vd INNER JOIN dbo.vCredit vc  ON vd.LedgerId=vc.LedgerId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to both Wikser and Trey as I had some syntax problem that was bring into my notice by them and after that my query still had problem.

Issue was- Net was an alias to my column and when i was checking it in case statement it was not able to find out the same column.

**ERROR**

```
select vd.LedgerId,(CreditAmt-DebitAmt) AS NET,
CASE 
   WHEN NET > 0 THEN 'Debit' 
   WHEN NET < 0 THEN 'Credit' 
   ELSE 'Nil' 
End
AS NetVal
from dbo.vdebit vd INNER JOIN dbo.vCredit vc  ON vd.LedgerId=vc.LedgerId
```

**Correction Made**

```
select vd.LedgerId,(CreditAmt-DebitAmt) AS NET,
CASE 
   WHEN (CreditAmt-DebitAmt) > 0 THEN 'Debit' 
   WHEN (CreditAmt-DebitAmt) < 0 THEN 'Credit' 
   ELSE 'Nil' 
End
AS NetVal
from dbo.vdebit vd INNER JOIN dbo.vCredit vc  ON vd.LedgerId=vc.LedgerId
```

Comment: Yes, you can use aliases only in the ORDER BY clause of a t_sql, ´cause it is in the only part of the sentence that the new names of the columns are already known.

Answer (score 1):

When using a searched case expression, the syntax is like:

```
CASE
   WHEN NET > 0 THEN 'Debit'
   WHEN NET < 0 THEN 'Credit'
   ELSE 'Nil'
END
```

So just replace CASE NET with CASE.

Comment: @Wikser: I dont know what the issue is, but this still is not working

Answer (score 0):

First you are using both a **input expression** and **boolean expressions** in your case at the same time ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)).  It also looks like you are trying to assign the value of that case statement to a variable, but your syntax is incorrect.  I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
select vd.LedgerId,(CreditAmt-DebitAmt) AS NET,
CASE WHEN NET > 0 THEN 'Debit' WHEN NET < 0 THEN 'Credit' ELSE 'Nil' End
AS NetVal
from dbo.vdebit vd INNER JOIN dbo.vCredit vc  ON vd.LedgerId=vc.LedgerId
```

Comment: Still same problem is being displayed

Comment: Wikser's answer is your primary problem.  I missed it before.